# Maya userSetup.py not executing on startup from network location using env vars

Tags: python, maya

I've set an environment variable to point to a scripts folder where i placed `userSetup.py` however the script never seems to run. Here is my configuration.

following env var is set:

```
MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH = 'Q:Studio\pipeline\apps\maya\scripts'
```

In this folder i have a python script **userSetup.py**

```
################################################################################
# Imports
################################################################################
import os
import sys


def main():
    print('----------main----------')


def init():
    print('----------executeDeferred----------')


main()
executeDeferred(init)
```

When i launch maya i would expect it to show the print statement for the deferred fn. however nothing ever shows. What's wrong here?

keep in mind the users could have local usersetup.py files, however this is a py file so it should still execute.

Comment: Did you try to set the `PYTHONPATH` env variable? A few days ago I tried to help someone who had a similiar problem and in his case the PYTHONPATH modification helped. `executeDeferred` seems not to be a valid command as much as I can say. There is one called `evalDeferred`. If it is not a valid command, you should see something in the output window.

Comment: What does the pythonpath have to do with this though?

Comment: executeDeferred is a python function. evalDeffered is the mel equivalent

Comment: Well... it is a python script and it seems make sense if it is placed in a path where it can be found by the python interpreter, what is the pythonpath. Can you give me a hint where I can find out more about `executeDeferred`? I was unable to find anything about it.

Comment: This is what I get if I use your script (with PYTHONPATH):----------main----------
Failed to execute userSetup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2023\Python\lib\site-packages\past\builtins\misc.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec_(code, myglobals, mylocals)
  File "C:/daten/userSetup.py", line 17, in <module>
    executeDeferred(init)
NameError: name 'executeDeferred' is not defined

Comment: Hope someone with similar problem read this... I've tried to set the `MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH` to a custom location for the execution of `userSetup.py` but nothing happen until, as @haggikrey commented, you set the `PYTHONPATH`. Just to clarify this point, Im using the maya version 2022.5 and the documentation does not mentioned something about the `userSetup.py` for the variable `MAYA_SCRIPT_PATH` , [link](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-228CCA33-4AFE-4380-8C3D-18D23F7EAC72), in the same docuementation the `PYTHONPATH` is described... test both, the good one is `PYTHONPATH`